# How to read one column texts with Google Cloud Vision API

Tags: ocr, google-cloud-vision, text-recognition, cloud-document-ai

I have the next document image:

[image]

When I try to convert the image to text, the result is this:

```
Top Text

Ref: Rad: Dte: Ddo:

Ejecutivo 76520400300 Banco de Bogotá Luz Adriana

Bottom Text
```

The problem is Google API recongnize it like two columns so, How can I config the Google API in order to obtain one column text?

My goal is obtain:

```
Top Text

Ref:Ejecutivo  Rad:  76520400300 Dte: Banco de Bogotá Ddo:Luz Adriana

Bottom Text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google team member responded that [Document AI](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/overview) works better than Cloud Vision as per the update on [the issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/209211671)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30561877)

Answer (score 0):

**Cloud Vision API** doesn't have a specific request property to specify the format used to read or sort the file's data. Instead, I think that the available workaround is to use the [BoundingPoly](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.vision.v1#google.cloud.vision.v1.BoundingPoly) and [Vertex](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.vision.v1#vertex) response properties, that display the coordinates related to each word contained in the image, in order to process the vertices data within your code logic and define the text that need to be grouped by columns and rows. You can take a look on [this link](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#text_detection_responses) which includes some response examples that include these properties.

In case this feature doesn't cover your current needs, you can use the **Send Feedback** button, located at the lower left and upper right corners of the [service public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/), as well as take a look the [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) tool in order to [raise a Vision API feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187174&template=0) and notify to Google about this desired functionality.

Comment: [Archived page for the link](https://web.archive.org/web/20190107163537/https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr) in the previous answer about examples of Bounding poly and vertex responses