# Google vision API two columns image text extraction getting messed up

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-vision

I'm using the Google vision API (node.js) with the `DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION`feature type. It's extracting text correctly but messing up the column sequence. I expect it should return the first column's text first and then the other column's text accordingly. Please have a look at the input image and extracted text.[image: The input image]

Extracted text from the response json's `fullTextAnnotation.text` property.

```
Samanburður á upplifun starfsmanna
131
saman starfsánægju hjá starfsmönnum í
einkareknum og opinberum fyrirtækjum eru
misvísandi (Demoussis og Giannakopoulos,
2007; Macklin, Smith og Dollard, 2006) og því
er erfitt að spá fyrir um það hvort starfsánægja
sé meiri innan hóps opinberra starfsmanna eða
starfsmanna einkageirans hér á landi.
Broeck (2007) kemur fram að starfsmenn hins
opinbera upplifa minni togstreitu milli vinnu og
fjölskyldu en starfsmenn einkageirans.
Síðustu ár hafa fræðimenn bent á mikilvægi
þess að rannsaka í meira mæli jákvæðar hliðar
á samspili milli vinnu og einkalífs. Auðgun
(e. enrichment) milli starfs og fjölskyldu á sér
stað þegar þátttaka á einu sviði (t.d. fjölskyldu)
verður auðveldari með reynslu eða færni sem
þróast á hinu sviðinu (vinnu). Með öðrum orðum
á auðgun sér stað þegar reynsla eða úrræði sem
notað er á einu sviði bætir frammistöðu á hinu
(Carlson, Kacmar, Wayne og Grzywacz, 2006;
Frone, 2003; Greenhaus og Poweel, 2006).
Rannsóknir benda til þess að auðgun hafi jákvæð
tengsl við lífs- og starfsánægju (Hill, 2005;
Wayne, Musisca og Fleeson, 2004), ánægju
í hjónabandi (Hill, 2005), tilfinningatryggð
(e. affective commitment; Wayne, Randel og
Stevens, 2006) og neikvæð tengsl við streitu
(Hill, 2005). Líkt og í erlendum rannsóknum
sýndu niðurstöður úr rannsókn Auðar Örnu
Arnardóttur og félaga (2007) að þeir sem
upplifðu auðgun í starfi voru ánægðari í starfi,
ánægðari með fjölskylduna og lífið og sýndu
fyrirtæki sínu jafnframt meiri hollustu.
Tengsl starfsmanns við vinnustað og
vinnuveitanda
Eitt af meginverkefnum vinnuveitenda í sífellt
harðari samkeppni um hæft starfsfólk snýst
um að halda í bestu starfskraftana. Ein leið til
þess að festa starfsmenn í sessi er að rækta með
þeim hollustu gagnvart fyrirtækinu og hvetja til
þegnhegðunar af þeirra hálfu.
Hollusta starfsmanns við fyrirtækið
Hollusta (e. commitment) hefur verið einn af
miðpunktum rannsókna um sambandið milli
einstaklings og fyrirtækis. Hollustu er ekki
hægt að þvinga fram hjá starfsmanni heldur
verður hún að koma fram af sjálfsdáðum og er
hún jafnframt persónubundin (Swailes, 2002).
Porter og félagar (1974) skilgreina hollustu
starfsmanns sem það að starfsmaður upplifi
sig sem hluta af fyrirtækinu og taki virkan
þátt í starfsemi þess. Rannsóknir hafa fundið
jákvæð tengsl á milli mats starfsfólks á eigin
hollustu við löngun til að halda áfram störfum
hjá fyrirtækinu (Loi, Ngo, 2006), við vellíðan í
starfi (sjá Cook og Wall, 1980 í Swailes, 2002)
og neikvæð tengsl við fjarvistir (Lyness og
Thompson, 1997). Rannsókn Lyons, Duxbury
og Higgins (2006) sýndi einnig að starfsmenn
í einkareknum fyrirtækjum sýna meiri hollustu
en starfsmenn í opinberum fyrirtækjum.
Starfsánægja
Ánægja í starfi snýst um hvernig starfsmaður
metur starf sitt út frá starfsreynslu sinni,
væntingum sínum til starfsins og samanburði
(Cranny, Smith og Stone, 1992; Locke, 1976).
Starfsánægja er mikilvægur forspárþáttur um
almenna vellíðan og hamingju fólks (Argyle,
2001). Hún snýr að einstökum þáttum í starfinu
eða á vinnustaðnum eins og launum, tegund
starfs, vinnuaðstæðum, yfirmönnum, stefnu
fyrirtækis og vinnuferlum, samskiptum við
samstarfsmenn, tækifærum til starfsþróunar
og stöðuhækkunum svo dæmi séu tekin
(Cranny, Smith og Stone, 1992; Riggio, 2003).
Rannsóknir sýna að starfsánægja hefur jákvæð
tengsl við stuðning frá fyrirtækinu (Rhoades
og Eisenberger, 2002), hollustu starfsmanns
(Riggio, 2003; Swailes, 2006; Yoon og Thye,
2002) og þegnhegðun (Podsakoff, o.fl., 2000).
Niðurstöður erlendra rannsókna sem bera
Þegnhegðun
Þegnhegðun (e. organizational citizenship
behavior) hefur verið skilgreind sem hegðun
sem er fyrirtækinu í hag og starfsmaður
sýnir að eigin frumkvæði (Podsakoff, o.fl.,
2000). Fimm þátta líkan Organs (1988)
skiptir þegnhegðun í fimm þætti: Fórnfýsi (e.
altruism), samviskusemi (e.conscientiousness),
drengskap (e. sportsmanship), tillitssemi
Sálfræðiritið, 13. árg. 2008
```

Comment: Is it possible to provide your code? It's in PDF or png format? Did you try to use `TEXT_DETECTION`?

Comment: @PjoterS Sure! It's for both PDF and image. Yes, I used but the result is the same. The main issue is two columns of text. Here is the code: https://pastebin.com/9bLz9n06

Comment: Cloud Vision is powered by Machine Learning models and sometimes results are different than we expected. As a workaround could you split those images however it would require much manual work. But you could try to use the [BoundingPoly](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.vision.v1#google.cloud.vision.v1.BoundingPoly) and [Vertex](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.vision.v1#vertex) response properties like mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54008336/11148139)

Comment: @PjoterS Hmm. The manual work is quite difficult because of everything I have to do inside AWS lambda. Also there has two column text PDF. Yes, I'm trying to sort block using `BoundingPoly` and `nomalizedVertex`. Thanks!

Comment: Any updates? Were you able to solve your issue with `BoundingPoly` and `nomalizedVertex`?

Comment: @PjoterS Not yet!

Comment: @PjoterS I have to handle the following files:

- https://storage.googleapis.com/atlas-primer-test-resources-dev/Logfraedi_Ingibjorg_Thorsteinsdottir_2010.pdf
- https://storage.googleapis.com/atlas-primer-test-resources-dev/Samanbur2008.pdf 
- https://storage.googleapis.com/atlas-primer-test-resources-dev/A_Business_Intelligence_Framework_for_Analyzing_Educational_Data_-_Short.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a workaround for this column issue.

As I mentioned in the comments, `Cloud Vision` is powered by Machine Learning models and results might be different depending on many factors. I think that in this scenario the issue is too big margin on the right side.

There are 2 common way to use [Cloud Vision - OCR](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr):

- `TEXT_DETECTION` - detects and extracts text from any image.
- `DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION` - extracts text from an image, but the response is **optimized for dense text and documents**.

In the [Cloud Vision Demo](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/drag-and-drop) I have tested the original image and image with smaller margin and got expected results.

I have used 3rd party software [Deftpdf](https://deftpdf.com/resize-pdf) to reduce margins in the OP's [example PDF](https://storage.googleapis.com/atlas-primer-test-resources-dev/Samanbur2008.pdf). Later I have tested the following [Detect text in files (PDF/TIFF)](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf) documentation (used python code with `document_text_detection`  and `Google Cloud Storage`) and I've got expected results. First I've got the whole first column and later second column text.

Some kind of workaround would be also to configure [BoundingPoly](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.vision.v1#google.cloud.vision.v1.BoundingPoly) and [Vertex](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.vision.v1#vertex) response properties like mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949316/how-to-read-one-column-texts-with-google-cloud-vision-api/54008336#54008336).